# Change IIS session expiration

Tags: powershell, iis

[IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quLvZ.png)

Hello! Can someone please help me with some details on what I need to change in order to set the session expiration to a lower value?

Currently timeout is set to 20 minutes but 30 days for expiration seems a bit too much. I would like to change this to 1 or 2 hours.

Thanks!

Comment: What's that page? It might be a Microsoft product, but not IIS.

Comment: It`s PowerShell Web Access

Comment: Then that's PowerShell session timeout and has nothing to do with IIS.

Comment: Your probably right but still i can`t seem to find any setting to change this .... :)

Comment: But this would be an off-topic question for the Q&A since it is not a PowerShell code issue but a product/Windows feature/service configuration concern. So, this really should be posted to say SuperUser or the like. Anyway, if the MS docs don't provide the info (which I've never seen them have this particular from all I've seen to date) for this setting, then it's a catch22. Even the PowerShell timeout settings is flaky, as I've not had it work consistently. Generall, pssessions are handled by $PSSessionOption. See the docs ABOUT_PREFERENCE_VARIABLES

Comment: Have you monitored whether the connection get expired after 20 minutes? Because It looks like Web access will disconnect the connection based on the session timeout property.

Comment: that part works, at 20 min the user is logged off from the website but still the session can be reopened if credentials are reentered. That part i would like to change so the session is deleted after 2-3 h instead of a expiration date of 30 days as you can see in the attached image. A bit stuck at this step as nothing I tried up to this point seems to work